# Edit Text MotionEventActions when 'IsEnabled=False'

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have that show/hide pass feature and it works just fine. One of my views ilustrated below has a security code that effect is also applied on Entry Text that has property '`IsEnabled=False`'. Right now when I click on an eye nothing happens.

Is there any way to get it working when text entry is not enabled?

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="1" IsVisible="{Binding IsPINSectionVisible}">
            <Label 
                Style="{StaticResource MessageLabelStyle}"
                Text="{i18n:Translate Pin_Text}">
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" IsVisible="{Binding IsPINSectionVisible}">
            <Entry Text="{Binding PIN.Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   IsEnabled="False"
                   IsPassword="True"
                   Placeholder="{i18n:Translate Pin_Title}">
                <Entry.Style>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Style"
                                Android="{StaticResource EntryStyle}" />
                </Entry.Style>
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
                        EventName="TextChanged"
                        Command="{Binding ValidatePINCommand}" />
                </Entry.Behaviors>
                <Entry.Effects>
                    <effects:ShowHidePassEffect />
                </Entry.Effects>
                <Entry.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                        TargetType="Entry"
                        Binding="{Binding PIN.IsValid}"
                        Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="behaviors:LineColorBehavior.LineColor"
                                Value="{StaticResource ErrorColor}" />
                        <Setter Property="Entry.PlaceholderColor"
                                Value="{StaticResource ErrorColor}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Entry.Triggers>
            </Entry>
```

And Android Effect class:

```
 public class ShowHidePassEffect : PlatformEffect
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        ConfigureControl();
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
    }

    private void ConfigureControl()
    {
        EditText editText = ((EditText)Control);
        editText.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, Resource.Drawable.pass_show_24, 0);
        editText.SetOnTouchListener(new OnDrawableTouchListener());
    }
}

public class OnDrawableTouchListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Views.View.IOnTouchListener
{
    public bool OnTouch(Android.Views.View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (v is EditText && e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
        {
            EditText editText = (EditText)v;
            if (e.RawX >= (editText.Right - editText.GetCompoundDrawables()[2].Bounds.Width()))
            {
                if (editText.TransformationMethod == null)
                {
                    editText.TransformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.Instance;
                    editText.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, Resource.Drawable.pass_show_24, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    editText.TransformationMethod = null;
                    editText.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, Resource.Drawable.pass_hide_24, 0);
                }

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And picture to ilustrate the view:
[image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing a basic demo to reproduce this problem? to make sure we are verifying the exact same thing you are using.

Comment: Basically, the entry for the pin is not enabled, this effects the show/hide pass feature (the eye) also being not clickable. The req is to have it not enabled (text entry) but I wish to have the eye clickable. Hope this helps.

Comment: What about place the eye in an `Image` and add a [Tap Gesture Gesture Recognizer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/) in this `Image`?